# How to find all the points of a given graph line

Tags: matlab, plot

Hi everyone I want to find all the points from a plot and save it in array

for example I've this graph I want all the point from the beginning of the line to the end of it

```
% Drawing a Trajectory
prompt={'Enter The Number Of Lines:'};  % Enter statements at the Command Window to accept input from you.
title='Draw Line '; % Name the Command Window
n=inputdlg(prompt); % Create and open input dialog box
A = sscanf(n{1}, '%d'); % Convert from String to Int
[x,y] = ginput(A); % Graphical input from mouse or cursor
plot(x,y)
posth = [x,y];  % Save 'x' and 'y' as Array
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: You already have them. The x-coordinates are stored in `x` and the y-coordinates in `y`.

Comment: Dan455 there is no problem with the cod I just want to find all the points for the Trajectory I'm drawing using this code

Comment: horchler: yeah I know that but I want the all the coordinates in the line. For example between (x(1),x(2)) and (y(1),y(2))

Comment: [There are an infinite number of coordinates on a line.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment)

Comment: Do you mean the coordinates of the pixels on the screen used to draw the line? Please formulate your question clearly.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454409/getting-intermediate-points-generated-by-plot-in-matlab?rq=1 I think it may be what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain `x` and `y` with only the plot after the fact, in this case you can do:

```
line_handles = get(gca,'Children');
x = get(line_handles,'XData');
y = get(line_handles,'YData');
```

where [`gca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) refers to the current axis of the current figure (you can replace it with the handle, `h`, of the plot, i.e., change your code to `h = plot(x,y)`). If there is only one line, `x` and `y` will be vectors. If there are multiple lines, they will be cell arrays.

You can also output `x` and `y` simultaneously as a cell array via:

```
xy = get(get(gca,'Children'),{'XData','YData'});
```

where

```
x = xy{1,:};
y = xy{2,:};
```

Comment: What did you do exactly here bro ??? In the end you got the same coordinates I had from the plot

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it does -extract `x` and `y` from the figure.

Comment: You didn't get what I want bro. What I want is to find all the points of the drawing line. In another words all the points between (x(1),y(1)) and (x(2),y(2))

Comment: You'll need a bigger hard drive, as @Doresoom said above, there are an infinite number of points between `[x(1),y(1)]` and `[x(2),y(2)]` (assuming that that the points aren't coincident). Even in floating point there are an enormous number of distinct values. So we don't understand what else you could be asking. Pixels?

Comment: I'm using this line as a trajectory for a moving object. I want the point's so I can compare it with the coordinates in ral time so I can correct the path for the moving object.

Comment: So you want the equations for the lines. And then you want to interpolate those lines following some criteria -actually just the points (rather than the line equations) are probably sufficient for most interpolation functions in Matlab. I suggest that you do some more research on this problem and really figure out what you're trying to do and how to describe. Draw some pictures. I don't think any of us had a clue to what you were asking with this question beyond my attempt at an answer and the fact that you already have `x` and `y`.

Comment: the funny thing I can't upload any pictures I think I don't have the privilege to do that

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/myfiles/#


Let's say I've this trajectory I already have the coordinates of the red points and this is the theor trajectory. Now I'm moving an object "let say it's a robert" and I'm tracking the movement in real time that's mean I've the real time (x,y) when I want to correct the path of the robert I'll compare the reat time coordinates with the theory coordinates "the line I drew coordinates " that's mean I need to know all the line (x,y) so I can compare it